# How to get a txt file to a string variable Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, text

Im finding a lot of complicated answers however, I know there is a simple way and Im just not fitting it together.

I want the txt file to be put into the String `txtString`.  `inFS` is for later parsing.  What do I need to put the txt file to the string `txtString`?

My code:

```
fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("mytextfile.txt");
inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);         
txtString = ??
```

Comment: What ways are you finding? while loops that ensure the file has a next line?

Comment: If you have the latest version of Java: String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("readMe.txt")));

Comment: Nope, it needs to be simple. What do i put where the ?? are in my post.

Answer (score 3):

```
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("mytextfile.txt")));
```

works with java7

Comment: You should always specify the encoding when using `new String(byte[] b)`.